# Bcdiv return before one value after another

Tags: php

I have a function

```
return bcdiv((float)($data), 100000000, 8);
```

from `$data = 100000000000000;`
it returns 0.00000000

I need 1000000.00000000

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove casting:

```php
return bcdiv($data, 100000000, 8); // "1000000.00000000"
```

`bcdiv()` returns a string.

When you use casting to float `return (float) bcdiv(...`, unnecessary zeroes will be omitted in this case: `float(1000000)`